# How can I avoid duplicate code in the if-else chain?

Tags: apex

I have the following code snippet

```
if(!setPass){
    this.teacher  = Ev_TeacherTestUtil.createTeacher
                    (sess, 'TestTeacher1', 
                    Ev_TeacherService.NOMINATED,
                    Ev_TeacherService.EMPLOYEE_NO, 
                    Ev_TeacherService.PASS_NO);
}else{
    this.speaker  = Ev_TeacherTestUtil.createTeacher
                    (sess, 'TestTeacher1', 
                    Ev_TeacherService.NOMINATED, 
                    Ev_TeacherService.EMPLOYEE_NO, 
                    Ev_TeacherService.PASS_YES);
}
```

The only change in the else condition is `Ev_TeacherService.PASS_YES` (in the if condition it is set to `Ev_TeacherService.PASS_NO`), the rest is just being duplicated! How can I avoid this?

Comment: importantly the assigning variable is differ in both cases isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, you can create a separate wrapper method that creates this object and call that by passing in the parameter that you want to customise..

here's a mockup

```
private YourObjectType createTeacher(boolean setPass){

  YourlastVariableType lastVar = setPass ? Ev_TeacherService.PASS_NO : Ev_TeacherService.PASS_YES;

  YourObjectType obj = Ev_TeacherTestUtil.createTeacher
                    (sess, 'TestTeacher1', 
                    Ev_TeacherService.NOMINATED,
                    Ev_TeacherService.EMPLOYEE_NO, 
                    lastVar);
  return obj;

}
```

and call it using

```
if(!setPass){
    this.teacher  = createTeacher(true);
}else{
    this.speaker  = createTeacher(false);
}
```

Comment: `createTeacher(true)` and `createTeacher(false)` have the disadvantage that it is not clear what the `true` and `false` mean. I would recommend creating wrapper methods `createTeacher()` and `createSpeaker()`, or `createWithPass()` and `createWithoutPass()`. More elaborate explanation over at [Martin Fowler's blog](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html).

Answer (score 3):

Apex supports the [ternary if/else](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm) that (where the object is being assigned to one variable) can be helpful to avoid code duplication:

```
this.sameVariable = Ev_TeacherTestUtil.createTeacher(
        sess,
       'TestTeacher1', 
        Ev_TeacherService.NOMINATED, 
        Ev_TeacherService.EMPLOYEE_NO, 
        setPass ? Ev_TeacherService.PASS_YES : Ev_TeacherService.PASS_NO
        );
```

Comment: that was my initial thot.. but jus resisted becos its being assigned to 2 different variables..

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I posted this answer because some people seem to avoid ternary ifs at all cost but often they are a clean solution and I wanted to illustrate that. But agreed not so much here with the two variables.